# Why does this call to DSProxy fail?

Tags: storage, delegatecall, calldata, encoding, dsproxy

Take these two contracts, both deployed on Kovan and with the source code verified:

- DSProxy: [0xa92Bed719071A4d33B0B348513E7e866a6ff6B3F](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xa92bed719071a4d33b0b348513e7e866a6ff6b3f)
- TargetContract: [0xE3CD2e7a628b57d3e50c5f7B921182f676721bDF](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xe3cd2e7a628b57d3e50c5f7b921182f676721bdf)

And take this transaction:

- [0x04c5e3b87dfeaae07ea73242663c69bd7e412686ffc0fcc25016fc6179455e56](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x04c5e3b87dfeaae07ea73242663c69bd7e412686ffc0fcc25016fc6179455e56)

Which has been reverted and I don't understand why.

I want to call the `execute(address,bytes)` function of the `DSProxy` and pass in the following arguments:

- 0xE3CD2e7a628b57d3e50c5f7B921182f676721bDF
- 0xb081b4eb (the signature for the "wrapEth" function)
- Also send some amount of ETH

Effectively calling the [wrapEth](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xe3cd2e7a628b57d3e50c5f7b921182f676721bdf#writeContract) payable function defined in `TargetContract`, but via the `DSProxy` DELEGATECALL functionality.

[With help from ethers.js](https://gist.github.com/paulrberg/966ff22cd29bfbaab3b97cec065e5310), I generated the calldata for this multi-contract call, and it looks like this:

```
0x1cff79cd000000000000000000000000e3cd2e7a628b57d3e50c5f7b921182f676721bdf00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004b081b4eb00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Unfortunately, when I relay this calldata to the Kovan testnet via MetaMask, MyCrypto or any other wallet, I am getting reverted transactions. Although I feel that the above calldata is correct, I tried tweaking the last part of the bytes (the function signature) in case there is a bug in Ethers, but with no luck.

Can you see the error here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DSProxy uses delegatecall to call the target contract so inside  `wrapEth` you are accessing DSProxy storage and not TargetContract.

You are reading `weth` from the wrong storage and using something else as weth address.

One possible solution is pass `weth` as a parameter.

```
contract TargetContract {
    constructor() {}
    
    function wrapEth(WethInterface weth) public payable {
        weth.deposit{ value: msg.value }();
    }
}
```

Another solution is to make TargetContract to inherit from DSProxy and use a function to initialize weth.

```
contract TargetContract is DSProxy {

    WethInterface public weth;

    function initialize(WethInterface _weth) public {
        weth = _weth;
    }
    
    function wrapEth() public payable {
        weth.deposit{ value: msg.value }();
    }
}
```

Comment: I completely missed this. Thanks, Ismael! A 3rd solution is to define the WETH address as a constant.